# Showing Set is open using theorem

Tags: general-topology

Let S = $ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}| x>y\} $

I want to prove this by finding a continuous function $f$ given by $f(x,y) = x-y>0$ where S = $f^{-1}$ $(0, \infty)$

But $(0, \infty)$ doesn't seem to be the right pre-image and this $x>y$ is basically the region below the graph $y = x$ but I can't figure out the right pre-image that would work for the entire region?

What do I do here?

Comment: No, the  region  you choose is right .

Comment: Why does that not seem to be the correct preimage? (It is, but knowing that doesn't help your intuition)

Comment: A few points about terminology: You don't want to "find $f$" in this case, as you have already found it. You gave its definition. But it is just $x - y$, not $x - y > 0$. The $ > 0 $ part comes in with the choice of image set: $(0, \infty)$. Which brings up the other point: $(0, \infty)$ is the Image, not the pre-image, $S$ is the pre-image. (And as has already be pointed out, both sets are exactly right for what you need.)

Comment: I'm confused. I always thought Pre - image was like Domain and Image was like Range. So Domain of $x>y$ would be from negative infinity to positive infinity, so thought this pre image would be negative infinity to positive infinity for this question.

Comment: What's the domain of an inequality? You are correct, pre-image is in the domain, so in this case $S$ is the pre-image of $(0,\infty)$ via $f$, as Paul told you. And again, as Paul said, don't confuse inequalities and functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Clearly the Real valued function  $f(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2$.What is the preimage of $(0,\infty)$ under $f$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your choice is correct. $f^{-1}((0,\infty))=S$. Proof:

Let $(x,y)\in S$. Then $x>y$ and thus $f(x,y)=x-y\in(0,\infty)$ and thus $(x,y)\in f^{-1}((0,\infty))$.

Let $(x,y)\in f^{-1}((0,\infty))$. Then $f(x,y)=x-y=a$ for some $a\in(0,\infty)$. Thus $x=y+a>y$ and thus $(x,y)\in S$.